# Change position of Play video on item click in ListView

Tags: android, listview, video, scroll

I have ListView, it contain number of videos when I click on any item, The video is playing when scroll up or down the video become stop, I referred https://github.com/danylovolokh/VideoPlayerManager It is working fine but when I click on any item which is not 100 percent visible on screen like this:

[image]

At that time the below item video is playing, like this:

[image]

I checked the position in log when i click on any item but i getting right position in the log, So what can i do? Please guys help to solve it. I faced this issue from many days

My Code is below:

```
public class PlayVideo extends Activity {
        private Activity mActivity;
        private static final boolean SHOW_LOGS = Config.SHOW_LOGS;
        private static final String TAG = PlayVideo.class.getSimpleName();
        private ArrayList<BaseVideoItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        private String videoId = "";
        public static int isVideoPlay = 0;
        public static ProgressDialog pDialog;
     private final ListItemsVisibilityCalculator mListItemVisibilityCalculator =
                new SingleListViewItemActiveCalculator(new DefaultSingleItemCalculatorCallback(), mList);
    private ItemsPositionGetter mItemsPositionGetter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_video_list_view);

            mActivity = PlayVideo.this;

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);

            try {
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", R.drawable.video_sample_1_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp", R.drawable.video_sample_3_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", R.drawable.video_sample_4_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", R.drawable.video_sample_1_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", R.drawable.video_sample_2_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", R.drawable.video_sample_3_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
                mList.add(ItemFactory.createItemFromUrl(mActivity, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", R.drawable.video_sample_4_pic, mActivity, mVideoPlayerManager));
     } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            VideoListViewAdapter videoListViewAdapter = new VideoListViewAdapter(mVideoPlayerManager, mActivity, mList);
            mListView.setAdapter(videoListViewAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d("isVideo------------", String.valueOf(isVideoPlay));
                    if (isVideoPlay == 0) {
                        pDialog.show();
                        Log.d("Position....", String.valueOf(position));
                        mItemsPositionGetter = new ListViewItemPositionGetter(mListView);
                        Log.d("mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()....", String.valueOf(mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()));
                        Log.d("mListView.getLastVisiblePosition()....", String.valueOf(mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()));
                        Log.d("mItemsPositionGetter....", String.valueOf(mItemsPositionGetter));
                        mListItemVisibilityCalculator.onScrollStateIdle(mItemsPositionGetter, mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(),
                                mListView.getLastVisiblePosition());
    }
      }
            });
    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    mScrollState = scrollState;
                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && !mList.isEmpty()) {
                        if(isVideoPlay == 1){
                            isVideoPlay = 0;
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
      }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    if (!mList.isEmpty()) {
                        if(isVideoPlay == 1){
                            isVideoPlay = 0;
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }
     }
                }
            });
        }
    private final VideoPlayerManager<MetaData> mVideoPlayerManager = new SingleVideoPlayerManager(new PlayerItemChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerItemChanged(MetaData metaData) {
                if (SHOW_LOGS) Logger.v(TAG, "onPlayerItemChanged " + metaData);
            }
        });

        private int mScrollState = AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE;

        private ListView mListView;
     @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            // we have to stop any playback in onStop
            mVideoPlayerManager.resetMediaPlayer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please help to solve this problem!!!